# I have wrong result with sorting sting numbers

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a folder with names of files and I want to do list with that names and sort it, but the result is weird. Do you know what I do wrong?

```
list = [ '10.50-178.pom', '15.00-178.pom','100.0-178.pom', '11.00-178.pom', '110.0-178.pom',
'120.0-178.pom', '130.0-178.pom', '10.00-178.pom', '140.0-178.pom' ]

print(sorted(list))
```

result: `['10.00-178.pom', '10.50-178.pom', '100.0-178.pom', '11.00-178.pom', '110.0-178.pom', '120.0-178.pom', '130.0-178.pom', '140.0-178.pom', '15.00-178.pom']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to indicate that the first five characters are actually a number, because now every character is considered separetly.

```
lista = ['10.50-178.pom', '15.00-178.pom', '100.0-178.pom', '11.00-178.pom', '110.0-178.pom',
        '120.0-178.pom', '130.0-178.pom', '10.00-178.pom', '140.0-178.pom']

def take_elem(elem):
    return float(elem[:4])

sorted_list = sorted(lista, key=take_elem)
print(sorted_list)
```

Comment: Should probably be `elem[:5]`